# How to change color of field in form when is full with css?

Tags: css

I need form like that: 
[image: picture click]

So when field is full i want color: blue;

How to code that with css.

must be something like:

```
.formfield:?? {
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);"` and in css `.formfield:not([value=""])` and **set `border-color` not `color`**

```css
.formfield:not([value=""]) {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input value="" class="formfield" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);"/>
```

**If you set validation to input like `required`**

```css
.formfield:valid { border-color: blue; }
```

```html
<input class="formfield" required>
```

Comment: do you set validation on input